# AVPlayer volume control while playing Video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, iphone-5

I am working on custom video Player using `AVPlayer` class now in that i want to implement volume control using with `UISlider`control.

I have done this:

```
NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams =[AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
[audioInputParams setVolume:volumeSlider.value atTime:kCMTimeZero];
[allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
AVMutableAudioMix *audioZeroMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioZeroMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];
[self.playerItem setAudioMix:audioZeroMix];
```

But its not working for me so can anyone please suggest me any other solution for this i have done so much r&d but not able to find proper solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to change volume :

```
NSArray *audioTracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];

NSMutableArray *allAudioParams = [NSMutableArray array];
for (AVAssetTrack *track in audioTracks) {
  AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *audioInputParams = 
    [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParameters];
  [audioInputParams setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
  [audioInputParams setTrackID:[track trackID]];
  [allAudioParams addObject:audioInputParams];
}

AVMutableAudioMix *audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
[audioMix setInputParameters:allAudioParams];

[playerItem setAudioMix:audioMix];
```

Comment: But this is not working with Live Stream(playlist.m3u8) any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)doVolumeFade
{  
    if (self.player.volume > 0.1) {
        self.player.volume = self.player.volume - 0.1;
        [self performSelector:@selector(doVolumeFade) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];       
     } else {
        // Stop and get the sound ready for playing again
        [self.player stop];
        self.player.currentTime = 0;
        [self.player prepareToPlay];
        self.player.volume = 1.0;
    }
}
```